# What's the best workflow for designers to work with the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, workflow, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

I'm working in a resources heavy Rails 3.1.2 app as a frontend/designer and i'm constantly changing stylesheets (compass), reloading browser, ...

Since we switched to asset pipeline, it compiles scss, js, ... and it just take ages (30s/page).
Impossible to work fast as a designer in such an environment.

Here my dev config:

```
# from dev_tweaks gem
config.dev_tweaks.autoload_rules do
  keep :all

  skip '/favicon.ico'
  # Commented out to prevent scss caching
  # skip :assets
  skip :xhr
  keep :forced
end

config.assets.debug = false
config.cache_classes = false
```

Is there a magical config/settings/gem that would allow to compile only what has been changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [serve](http://get-serve.com) [(source)](https://github.com/jlong/serve) is something for you? It is a small project that will allow to create a design for a rails app, but without a complete rails app. So this will enable to work fast.

Of course, you do add an extra step: when your design is ready, it still has to be copied over to your actual rails app. But I think that is ok. Just use serve during the designing phase.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah i thought about that one. It was soo much easier before ^^

Comment: I understand that :) I added another option, which might just be enough for you.

Comment: Well actually if you have many files to request, it takes much longer than with debug false, because the addition of all time spended to make each request is bigger than the time it takes to precompile everything. 

What i did and works for me: I precompiled all assets in public. Then removed the one i was working on. So all normal asset are cached except the ones I need. 

Probably not the best way, but that works for the moment

Comment: nice tip RE source gem, that looks great - PS, you want to keep debug set to false if you are worried about speed